# How to Merge Identical Tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge

How to Merge Identical Tables in **PostgreSQL** forcing different serial numbers.

**My scenario**: first column is a bigserial number that are primary keys set to auto grow by increment 1 in a sequence. but they all start with 1,2,3,4.... in both tables.

Table: Data1

```
1|A
2|B
3|C
```

Table: Data2

```
1|D
2|E
3|F
```

Results should be:

```
1|A
2|B
3|C
4|D
5|E
6|F
```

Required criteria: the serial numbers should remain unique for all rows after merging.

I have two questions:

1. Can someone help me figure out how to create a query to merge two identical tables in PostgreSQL 8.4+ or 9+?
2. Is there a way within PostgreSQL commands or PgAdmin or some utility to directly merge the two tables?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (    
    SELECT row_number() over () as rn, 
          code
    FROM ( 
      SELECT code 
      FROM table_1
      UNION 
      SELECT code
      FROM table_2
    ) as t1
 ) as t2
 ORDER BY rn
```

Using the above result you can create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
AS
SELECT ....
```

Comment: You want UNION ALL there rather than UNION (which will eliminate duplicate "code" values)

Comment: I thought about that as well, but I'm not entirely sure. It's not clear from the examples and user1227809 didn't mention anything that would indicate that duplicates should be kept.

Answer (score 0):

This way you

- keep all rows (including duplicates)
- keep unchanged IDs for values from the first table
- keep IDs you can match to the second table

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT max(id) AS x
    FROM tbl1
    ) 
SELECT id, val
FROM   tbl1
UNION  ALL
SELECT x + id, val
FROM   tbl2, x
ORDER  BY id;
```

You need PostgreSQL 8.4 or later for the [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html).
You could just have a look at the maximum of `tbl1` and increment IDs from `tbl2` by a nice round number greater than that.

If you don't care about previous IDs, get rid of duplicate values and have IDs without gaps (initially), then @a_horse'e answer is better for you.